# gradiente de cor R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como faço para alterar a cor do gráfico de forma gradiente com a variável  anos,começando do branco ao vermelho intenso.

```
colourCount = length(unique(tabela.estacao$ano))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Reds"))

ggplot(tabela.estacao, aes(x=mes, y=tempMedia, group=as.factor(ano) )) +
geom_smooth(aes(colour = ano)) + ggtitle(est) + scale_fill_manual(name="Min-Max-Range and Mean \nof specific Croptypes",
values=getPalette(colourCount))
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro"))
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Brunna, utilize o comando `dput(tabela.estacao)` e cole o resultado em sua pergunta. Assim, o teu conjunto de dados será compartilhado e ficará mais fácil para te ajudarmos. Não é necessário compartilhar tudo, caso sejam dados sigilosos: basta uma quantidade de dados mínima que permita a reprodução do teu código original.

Comment: Neste [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/) você pode encontrar muitas informações básicas sobre opções de parâmetros gráficos no R usando ggplot2.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar uma chamada para a função `scale_colour_continous`.

Em exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)
dados <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), ano = rep(2010:2014, each = 20))
ggplot(dados, aes(x = x, y = y, group = as.factor(ano))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = ano)) +
  scale_colour_continuous(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]